# Do you need physical access to hack a BT land line before an outgoing call is made (dialing tone)

Tags: phone

Do you need physical access to hack a BT land line before an outgoing call is made (dialing tone)? I understand if you have physical access you could just put something in another phone socket. But, I can't easily find out whether BT have, at least in principle, access to my speaking voice while I am sent a dialling tone.

I am just a schizophrenic, but it'd be fun to know!

Comment: Back in the day when I worked on such things, yes, at the exchange you could hear what was being said by a subscriber being sent a dial tone.  Technology has moved on a very long way since then.

Comment: You should not use abbreviations like "BT" unless it is 100% clear what it means. In IT BT usually means BlueTooth but that would not make sense in this case.